# Counting size of string with regular expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having troubles getting the size of the URL i get with the regular expression. I can print the "exp" content but when i try to make an alert of exp.length it fails:

```
var pattern = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;            
var exp = text.match(pattern);

alert(exp.length);
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: text.length?? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, what you're trying to do is get the length of the regexp match result, you would do that like this:

```
var pattern = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;            
var exp = text.match(pattern);
if (exp) {
    alert(exp[0].length);
}
```

`.match()` returns either null (if no match was found) or an array.  In that array, exp[0] would be the whole match that was found.  Subsequent indexes in the array contain any subexpressions you matched (denoted with parentheses in the match string).

Answer (score 0):

string.match returns an array, not a string, you are probably trying to do something like this:

```
var pattern = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;            
var exp = text.match(pattern);

alert(exp.join('').length); // alert a string, not an array
```